# Why does PowerPoint uploads files to Microsoft?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerpoint, windows-store-app

Okay, so I use PowerPoint Mobile (the store app), and it shows this whenever I open a .ppt (pre-2007 PowerPoint) file.

[image: PowerPoint sends file to Microsoft online service]

It doesn't happen with newer .pptx formats. Also, it doesn't sometimes feel that it uploads the complete file as it happens pretty quickly but the file doesn't open if not connected to internet.

Why does this happen? Shouldn't it be privacy violation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has published very little technical information on PowerPoint Mobile, but according to the [PowerPoint Mobile license](https://support.office.com/legal?llcc=en-US&aid=OfficeMobileAppsEULA_en-us.htm), you agreed to these transmissions when you installed the app:

> **4. Privacy; Consent to Use of Data.** Your privacy is important to us. Some of the software features send or receive information when using those features. Many of these features can be switched off in the user interface, or you can choose not to use them. By accepting this agreement and using the software you agree that Microsoft may collect, use, and disclose the information as described in the Microsoft Privacy Statement available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=507380, and as may be described in the user interface associated with the software features.

(Link mine, bold formatting original.)

Nobody can know for sure why it sends these data, but here are my guesses, in descending order of likelihood:

1. PowerPoint Mobile doesn't understand the old pre-2007 formats. The binary PPT format is exceedingly complicated, and it's possible that Microsoft just didn't want to implement all that junk in a mobile app. If this is true, the transmission is so that a Microsoft server can translate the PPT into the new XML-based format (PPTX), or some other format that the app understands. This theory is strongly supported by the impossibility of opening PPTs without Internet access.
2. Microsoft wants to gather data on what features are used by people's documents. That information would be used to advise them as to what features from the old format should be implemented.
3. Microsoft just wants to know how many people are still using the old PPT format. That might explain the quick uploads; maybe it just sends the headers or a fragment.

The quick upload might also be explained by compression, but it's more likely that your Internet connection is so fast relative to the size of the slideshow (most aren't terribly large) that it's not a big deal.

Comment: thanks for explaining, and yes I agree on all points but why does it require to upload every file everytime? Also, my connection is not that fast (4MB file on a 4Mbps takes only a few 2-3 seconds).

Comment: #1 is probably the actual reason, and 2 & 3 would just be bonuses for MS. ;)

Comment: If you know it happens every time, stop loading .ppt files, and convert them to the newer format.

Comment: It's probably doing whatever it's doing each time you open a PPT because otherwise it'd have to store the results of whatever it's doing on your local device, which might end up eating all of your device's memory.